# Export and sharing Smalltalk projects

Tags: smalltalk

I’m trying to debug a Smalltalk (Squeak) project with a friend in a remote location. Apart from my project, it’s a stock Squeak 4.3 image.

Is there a way to send him just the project I’ve worked on instead of the entire image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the World menu, there is "Save project on file..." and "Load project from file..." but they seem to be broken. Loading a simple project caused an error "Key not found: MorphicModel4". I'll forward this to the dev list

Comment: Trying the “Save project on file” (typo?) also seems to cause the VM to hang on a progress bar. Bummer :(

Comment: Yes, typo. Thanks, I fixed the answer. As for the VM, make sure you have the latest for your platform. I use the ones from https://ci.lille.inria.fr/pharo/view/Cog/job/Cog-VM/, which are kept very current. On Mac Lion, I wasn't seeing any hanging

Comment: Whoa, cool! I didn’t know about the existence of other VMs. I’ll give this a shot later. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use Monticello. Its very easy to use and does versioning, merge and conflict resolving. It is also (somewhat) platform independent.